# Permission System (User, Groups, Special rights)

Tags: sql, join, permissions

Following scenario: Im currently trying to build a complex Permission system with MySQL using joins and so one. Most of it works like a charm, but my problem now is:

First of all, the setup of the tables:
(Sorry for external links, but the editor doesnt seems to work for me at the moment).

Tables: http://pastebin.de/36727
Data: http://pastebin.de/36726

Okay:

A user gets rights by being a member of a group. (That works!)

So, but now, i want to be able to provide a User with special rights (which are not included by an Group)

How could i do that?
Thats my try (but the problem is, if special rights exists, there not given back in the Result):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `user`.`username`,
    `right`.`name`

FROM
    `user`

INNER JOIN
    `user_group` ON
        `user`.`id` = `user_group`.`user_id`

INNER JOIN
    `group` ON
        `user_group`.`group_id` = `group`.`id`

INNER JOIN
    `group_right` ON
        `group`.`id` = `group_right`.`group_id`

INNER JOIN
    `right` ON
        `group_right`.`right_id` = `right`.`id`

LEFT JOIN
    `user_right` ON
        `user_right`.`user_id` = `user`.`id` AND
        `user_right`.`right_id` = `right`.`id`

WHERE
    `user`.`username` = 'Domi'
```

I hope you know what i mean, because my english is not that good.

Comment: Okay ive solved the problem myself using UNION. Thanks anyway :)